# .NET WebForms to DXA

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, upgrade

I’m curious to know if anyone has had any experience moving from .NET WebForms to DXA in 2013SP1. It appears all DXA documentation is geared towards new installs and doesn't cover existing Tridion installations.

My biggest concern is having to rewrite existing component schemas to work with DXA. My current install has about 35 existing publications, ~30k pages and a very sizable number of components.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change any of your Schemas, but you will have to create all required models and views, so this should be considered a complete new implementation (just as moving from ASP.NET WebForms to ASP.NET MVC would be).

Check out the topic of Semantic Mapping in our [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-2BED2168-26D2-465E-92D8-68C3D5219088), that explains how you can map existing Schema fields to a model. Which is what you can do in case you want to reuse any of the provided models and their views. But it might make a lot of sense that you create new models for all your Schemas. That is also explained in the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-B3CA619F-8FAF-4C6E-A3D3-DEDAF334919B).

Answer (score 1):

We created tools in our Alterian to Tridion upgrade project to generate Models and default razor template Views from the Tridion schema.

I will extract the functionality into tridion core service powershell and post a link to the code here.